# Finding Inverse of Matrix by using index notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, kronecker-product

I have this question in my homework:

[image]

I am not familiar with using kronecker delta or index notation to solve problem. I would like to ask if I have used the hint to express M and inverse of M, is it valid to do (q+w)(e+r)=qe+qr+we+wr just like algebra? or how to solve this question?

Comment: Yes, we can expand the product in that way.

Comment: Note that this question has nothing to do with the Kronecker product, despite your choice of tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
(c \delta_{ij} + d z_i z_j)(a \delta_{jk} + b z_j z_k)=\\
ac \; \delta_{ij}\delta_{jk} + bc z_j z_k \;\delta_{ij}
+ ad z_iz_j\;\delta_{jk} + bd\;z_iz_j^2z_k
$$
We then have (with the implied Einstein notation)
$$
(M^{-1})_{ij}M_{jk} = \\
\sum_{j=1}^n (ac \; \delta_{ij}\delta_{jk} + bc z_j z_k \;\delta_{ij}
+ ad z_iz_j\;\delta_{jk} + bd\;z_iz_j^2z_k) =\\
ac \;\delta_{jk} + (bc + ad)z_iz_k + bd z_iz_k\|z\|^2
$$

Comment: Thank You for your answer. It helps a lot and I think I can solve the problem!